# Simulate rnorm in R for many observations using mean and sd from each row

Tags: r, apply, simulation

I am attempting to apply the rnorm function to many rows (214) of a data frame in R.
I want to use the predefined row mean and sd values of each row of the data frame to complete the simulations and n=10,000 for all observations.

I would like to use the apply function to do this, however, I am unclear how to write the rnorm call within the apply function to accomplish this for all rows at once.

Reproducible example:

```
set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(
  Hazard = LETTERS[1:10],
  mean = sample(1:10),
  sd = c(0.14,0.23,0.21,0.27,0.12,0.19,0.21,0.18,
         0.29,0.22)
)
```

Code I tried:

```
dist <- rnorm(10000, mean=Data$mean, sd=Data$sd)

apply(X= Data,
      FUN = dist,
      MARGIN = 1)
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Incidentally, this web application for experimental data simulation may help people visiting this question: https://github.com/pablobernabeu/Experimental-data-simulation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be better to use `Map` here where we loop over the corresponding elements of 'mean', 'sd' column, apply the `rnorm` and returns a `list`

```
n <- 10000
lst1 <- Map(function(x, y) rnorm(n, mean = x, sd = y), Data$mean, Data$sd)
```

---

Or if we prefer `apply`, then subset the numeric columns of interest and loop over it

```
apply(Data[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) rnorm(n, mean = x[1], sd = x[2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be use `expand.grid` to generate a new dataframe for the simulations for each possible mean/std combination.

```
library(dplyr)
sim_data <-
  expand.grid(Hazard=Data$Hazard, iteration=1:10000) %>%
  left_join(Data) %>%
  mutate(x = rnorm(mean, sd))
```